# SQL design - should I be using many-to-many?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, many-to-many

First all, I'm new to StackOverflow and I did my best to search for related answers to this question before posting. Apologies if I've missed prior questions that would have answered my question.

I'm brand new to databases and I'm working through how to properly model a scenario. This would be a database for a shipping company. Shipments are picked up and delivered to various locations and whether or not it's a pickup or delivery at a location varies. That is, one day they might deliver a shipment to Location 1, another day they might pick up at Location 1 and deliver at a different Location. Each Shipment has an origin Location and destination Location.

At first I created a Shipments table and a Locations table, but I'm unsure about how to properly relate them to each other. Should I have an associative ShipmentsLocations table in between or should I be merging these columns into the existing tables? What would be the proper way to store two Locations, one that's for pickup and one for delivery, as they're both Location entities? Or is it my table design itself that's flawed?

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide to get me moving in the right direction. I'm still trying to wrap my head around these concepts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pickup and delivery, I would not use many-to-many with one relationship, but rather would add two columns to the shipment table. That is likely to simplify most ordinary queries I can think of. And, more importantly, that will let you easily enforce the rule that a Shipment does not have more than one delivery location, and not more than one origin location.

That is to say:

```
Shipment(Shipment_Id, Origin_Location_Id, Delivery_Location_Id, ...)
Location(Location_Id, ...)
```

Comment: Well that's a forehead-slapping moment for me. In all the texts/examples I've read, the FK in one table always matched exactly with the PK in another table. I didn't realize that I could have multiple columns, named differently, as FKs to the same PK of another table!